# In YUI, what is the difference between clientHeight, winHeight, and docHeight?

Tags: javascript, css, html, yui

In a code snippet, I saw lines like this:

```
  var headerHeight = Y.one('#header').get('clientHeight');
  var $body = Y.one('body');

  this.viewportH = $body.get('winHeight');
  this.docHeight = $body.get('docHeight');
```

As I understand, `clientHeight` is the same as `winHeight`, while `scrollHeight` is the same as `docHeight`. Is it true? If so, why does YUI gives them different names?

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**winHeight** Returns the inner height of the viewport - exludes scrollbar. it's your browser size (if you resize the browser there will be different values)

**docHeight** Returns the current height of the document, it's not what appears on screen, but all the page size.

Take a look here and click where is requiring:

http://www.wfimc.org/public/js/yui/3.0.0/examples/node/node-screen_clean.html

**clientHeight** Return the size of your frame exclude scroolbar:
Take a look on this event: `document.getElementById("client").onclick = function(){whatis('client');}` 
at:
http://jsfiddle.net/shibualexis/yVhgM/3/